# Extracting CN's with LDAP?

Tags: perl, ldap

I have this code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Net::LDAP;
use Data::Dumper;

my $dn="CN=...";
my $password="xxx";

my $ldap = Net::LDAP->new('example.com') or die "$@";
my $mesg = $ldap->bind($dn, password=>$password);
if ($mesg->code) { die "uuuu $mesg"; }

$mesg = $ldap->search(base => "dc=test,dc=example,dc=com", filter => "(name=LIST)",);

my $ref = $mesg->entry->get_value("member", asref => 1);
print Dumper $ref;

foreach my $string (@{$ref}) {
    $string =~ /CN=(.+?),.*/;
    print $1 . "\n";
}
```

which outputs the CN's using regular expressions:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
...
```

Using `Dumper` can I see the structure

```
$VAR1 = [
          'CN=aaaa,OU=test,DC=test,DC=example,DC=com',
          'CN=bbbb,OU=test,DC=test,DC=example,DC=com',
          'CN=cccc,OU=test,DC=test,DC=example,DC=com',
```

So I am wondering if there is a more "LDAP" way to extract these CN's, instead of using regular expressions?

**Update:**

Based on Javs answer this is the solution.

```
my $ref = $mesg->entry->get_value("member", asref => 1);

foreach my $string (@{$ref}) {
    print ldap_explode_dn($string)->[0]{CN} . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can:

```
use Net::LDAP::Util qw(ldap_explode_dn);
```

and use it on your attribute like this:

```
ldap_explode_dn($mesg->entry->get_value('member'));
```

to get this array of hashes:

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'CN' => 'aaaa'
      },
      {
        'OU' => 'test'
      },
      {
        'DC' => 'test'
      },
      {
        'DC' => 'example'
      },
      {
        'DC' => 'com'
      }
    ];
```

Comment: if I do that, and `print Dumper $cn;`, I get `$VAR1 = 'LIST';`.

Comment: @Sandra Schlichting Oh, sorry, now I get what you wanted. Check my edit.

Comment: If your ldap server is consistent about what it returns, then its as simple as `$dn->[0]{CN}` (where $dn is the result of ldap_explode_dn), otherwise you might want to check the resulting array and hashes.

Comment: `$dn->[0]{CN}` works but `$dn->[1]{CN}` doesn't. Since `Dumper` only dumps `$VAR1` I am getting the feeling that only that is available.

Comment: @sandra that's because you have several hashes there, and 'CN' is only on the first one.

Comment: I generally prefer to use `qw' ... '` on StackOverflow, it highlights better.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that CN is usually an attribute in LDAP directories?

Why not just query for the attribute CN for all returned objects?  Then no parsing required.

Comment: I don't know how to do that =( Can you give an example?

Comment: You would need to make new queries for each member in order to achieve this, while you can just parse what you already got.

Comment: @javs Good point.  I missed that the example was enumerating a groups members.